# Aggregate hourly data into monthly data starting with the yyyy-mm-dd h:m format in R

Tags: r, datetime

I've been actively looking for a solution to my question in R and did not find anything to solve my problem...

I have an R report to submit for the beginning of January, using pepe memes data. I am studying the price of pepe memes through times, and here comes my problem. I have the dates in the format `yyyy-mm-dd h:m`, and I want to aggregate those into means of monthly data. I was thinking about first making a new file, with my timestamp in format `yyyy-mm` but I am not able to this. I was successful when translating into the `yyyy-mm-dd` format, but I really have an issue when I want to go to the yyyy-mm format.

So, more clearly, here are my two questions :

- How do I aggregate my `yyyy-mm-dd h:m` dates into monthly ones with the average of monthly data (so, in the format `yyyy-mm`) ?
- If you do not know how to aggregate directly the dates, does any of you know how to go from the `yyyy-mm-dd h:m` format to the `yyyy-mm` one ?

Here are some rows of my dataset (just an abstract, it contains more than 250 rows):

```
   Timestamp           ForwardQuantity TotalPriceUSDPerUnit
------------------------------------------------------------
 1 2016-09-26 04:00:00               3                 3.44
 2 2016-09-26 04:00:00               7                 3.44
 3 2016-09-26 05:00:00               3                 3.39
 4 2016-09-26 05:00:00               1                 3.39
 5 2016-09-26 06:00:00               2                 3.39
 6 2016-09-26 13:00:00               4                 2.84
 7 2016-09-28 04:00:00               1                 2.88
 8 2016-09-28 04:00:00               1                 2.92
 9 2016-09-28 06:00:00               1                 2.92
10 2016-09-28 06:00:00               1                 2.92
```

Many thanks in advance, and have a nice christmas for those celebrating it!

EDIT : Result expected :

```
   Timestamp           Average price
 ------------------------------------
 1 2016-09               2.9981
```

Here the average price has been obtained by multiplying the forward quantity above with its related price

EDIT 2 : The output of dput(head(DatasHAIRPEPE3col, 10)) is the following

```
    structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1474862400, 1474862400, 
1474866000, 1474866000, 1474869600, 1474894800, 1475035200, 1475035200, 
1475042400, 1475042400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ForwardQuantity = c(3L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), TotalPriceUSDPerUnit = c(3.445, 3.445, 3.392, 3.392, 3.392, 
    2.8352, 2.8795, 2.9238, 2.9238, 2.9238)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end

**1) zoo** convert the data to a zoo object aggregating it at the same time to class `yearmon`.  That will give a zoo object `Mean` with one mean per year/month.  You can either use that  or convert it to a data.frame using `fortify.zoo`.  This solution is probably more convenient than (2) below since we directly represent the year/month as a `yearmon` class object which can be plotted and manipulated in a logical manner.

```
library(zoo)
Mean <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = mean)
fortify.zoo(Mean)  # optional
```

giving this data frame:

```
     Index     Mean
1 Sep 2016 3.406667
```

You could now further manipulate, e.g. plot it using `plot.zoo` like this:

```
plot(Mean)
```

**2) Base R** Alternately, use the first 7 characters of each timestamp to represent the year/month and aggregate by that.

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, Timestamp = substring(Timestamp, 1, 7))
aggregate(UsdPricePerUnit ~ Timestamp, DF2, mean)
```

giving:

```
  Timestamp UsdPricePerUnit
1   2016-09        3.406667
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Timestamp                    UsdPricePerUnit
2016-09-26 04:00:00                 3.44
2016-09-26 04:00:00                 3.44
2016-09-26 05:00:00                 3.39
2016-09-26 05:00:00                 3.39
2016-09-26 05:00:00                 3.39
2016-09-26 06:00:00                 3.39"
DF <- read.csv(textConnection(gsub("  +", ",", Lines)))
```

Comment: Hello man ! Many thanks for your answer, but when I enter the line Mean <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = mean) I have the following error : There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50) ...

Comment: I also tried the second method, but i gives me the mean per hour, not at all per month... If you know how to solve this, please let me know !!

Comment: Copy and paste the input in the Note at the end and then copy and paste the code. There are no errors or warnings and it does not give the the result by hour. You will have to figure out how your actual data (which we don't have) differs from what you have shown in the question.

Comment: I just did it and it does not work... But if it can help, my class of datas is "POSIXct" "POSIXt"  for my timestamps, integer for my forward quantity and numeric for the total USD price per unit

Comment: Unfortunately you did not do what I described in my comment since the timestamps are not POSIXct in the Note nor are they described as such in the question. That was the reason I provided it in reproducible form -- so there could not be any uncertainty.

Comment: Wow ok my bad I tried again and that worked !! Many thanks !!
However, It does not take into account the forward quantity (which is the number of memes traded) for the aggregation. I edited while you were posting I think, which is why it is not included in your answer. What should I change for this ?

Comment: It used the data as shown in the question at the time I answered it. I think you must have changed it afterwards.

Comment: Well, I edited it 41 min ago and you posted 42 min ago, so I really think that you were writing when I was editing. But no problem, I am not blaming you and you helped me to get on the way of the solution. But if you knew how to adapt to the 3 column, that would be awesome. Otherwise, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample data provided in a previous answer (with an additional month added for demonstration) along with `dplyr` and `anytime`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(anytime)

Lines <- "
Timestamp               ForwardQuantity         UsdPricePerUnit
2016-09-26 04:00:00     3                 3.44
2016-09-26 04:00:00     7                 3.44
2016-09-26 05:00:00     3                 3.39
2016-10-26 05:00:00     1                 3.39
2016-10-26 05:00:00     2                 3.39
2016-10-26 06:00:00     4                 3.39"

DF <- read.csv(textConnection(gsub("  +", ",", Lines)))
DF %>%
  mutate(month = format(anydate((Timestamp)), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(MonthlySpend = ForwardQuantity*UsdPricePerUnit) %>%
  summarise(QuanPerMon = sum(ForwardQuantity),
            SpendPerMon = sum(MonthlySpend)) %>%
  mutate(AveragePrice = SpendPerMon/QuanPerMon) %>%
  select(1,4)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  month   AveragePrice
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 2016-09         3.43
2 2016-10         3.39
```

EDIT - New data added to question

This worked for me with your data

```
df %>%
  mutate(month = format(anydate((Timestamp)), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(MonthlySpend = ForwardQuantity*TotalPriceUSDPerUnit) %>%
  summarise(QuanPerMon = sum(ForwardQuantity),
            SpendPerMon = sum(MonthlySpend)) %>%
  mutate(AveragePrice = SpendPerMon/QuanPerMon) %>%
  select(1,4)

# A tibble: 1 x 2
  month   AveragePrice
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 2016-09         3.24
```

Comment: Hello ! Many thanks but I edited my post, and there is the forward quantity to take into account... Any idea of how to do that ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the forward quantity data?

Comment: Well, I need it for the average price. The forward data corresponds to the quantity of memes exchange at the given timestamp, so that pretty much changes all

Comment: Can you add a sample of the desired end data to your question? I'm not sure what you are looking for is possible without adding additional columns to indicate total spend per month (`Quantity*Price`) along with a column indicating total quantity per month

Comment: Ok, I just did it in my first post (after EDIT). Thanks ! But no worries if I have to have a new column I will haha

Comment: Think I have changed my answer for the desired end result

Comment: When I am using your datas it works perfectly (and thanks for that !) but I can't manage it when using my whole data set... the name of it is DatasHAIRPEPE3col . I tried replacing it in the read.csv (instead of Lines) code but that just gets me error... Sorry, I might seem very newbie but this is the case...

Comment: Add the output of `dput(head(DatasHAIRPEPE3col, 10))` to your question to show what your dataset looks like. You may not need the `read.csv` section, as its turning the sample data into a usable file  structure

Comment: Ok, just did it, under EDIT 2 ! Nota Bene : when I am using your code without the csv and with replacing DF by DatasHAIRPEPE3col, I get the following error : 
" Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `month` must be length 251 (the number of rows) or one, not 502"

Comment: fuck wait, this is the modified version. I just replaced it with the right one.

Comment: Okkkkk I finally did it !!! Well, you did it actually, I just adapted it to my datas. Many thanks man (or woman) you saved my life !!!!